# Replaced $HTTP_GET_VARS with $_GET, but not working

Tags: php, php4

I have the following code, which is not working for me. I used to have $HTTP_GET_VARS instead of $_GET, but then updated to PHP 5, and now things are broken. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<?php
$_GET['SubCat'];
$_GET['Location'];
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx");
mysql_select_db("outdoors",$db);
if ($Location) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Longitude, URL, SiteName, Description FROM hunting WHERE SubCategory = '$SubCat' AND Location = '$Location' AND Status <> 'HIDDEN' ORDER BY SiteName",$db);
} else {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Longitude, URL, SiteName, Description FROM hunting WHERE SubCategory = '$SubCat' AND Status <> 'HIDDEN' ORDER BY SiteName",$db);
<More unrelated stuff after this>
```

The variable will be passed through a link like this :

```
hunting.php?SubCat=Hunting+Locations
```

Comment: You didn't stored the value from get and where is $location i do not found that variable??

Comment: Location is reserved for future functionality.

Comment: Isn't the value from $_GET stored in the variable I pass it, like 'SubCat'? I thought that's the way it worked.

Comment: actually your code should be like this $subcat = $_GET['SubCat']; $location = $_GET['location'];

Comment: Nice! That did the trick! Thank you very much! Any idea on an easy way to change those two lines on several dozen files at one on my server?

Comment: Its better to manually do it if its less than 15 files.. else you have do it using scripts...

Comment: Managed to do it manually...everything is good now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For your first question:**

You must store it in any variable such like this

```
$SubCat = $_GET['SubCat'];
$Location = $_GET['Location'];
```

Or refer to it directly.

**For your second question:**

> Any idea on an easy way to change those two lines on several dozen files at one on my server?

Use a global search function to cover your entire directory. You find it in any of the popular editors. The search for `$_GET['SubCat'];` and replace it by `$SubCat = $_GET['SubCat'];`. Just make sure it is an unique name.

**On a side note:**

You donot use any type checking or input escaping and directly put it in your sql statement. IT IS VERY **DANGEROUS**. Please use PDO or at least an escaping function before you pass it to avoid SQL injection attacks