# Replacing $_HTTP_GET_VARS with $_GET

Tags: php

This is a question about setting up variables in an array for a personal memory aid project analogous to the old paper-based flash cards, which I now want to dust off. A PHP programmer at my old work 5 years ago helped write the page - alas I have long since lost contact, and my PHP skills are rudimentary at best.

### Current Code (PHP4)

```
    <?php
# Setting up Variables
reset($HTTP_GET_VARS);
while(list($key,$value) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS))
{
    $$key = $value;
}

#set query string, current_id and current_index
$query_string = "sound=$sound&hint=$hint&type=$type";

if(!isset($current_id)) $current_id = "";

if(!isset($current_index)) $current_index = "";

#connect to MySQL
$conn = @mysql_connect( "localhost","xxxx","xxxx" )
  or die( "Sorry - could not connect to MySQL" );

#select the specified database
$rs = @mysql_select_db( "xxx", $conn )
  or die( "Sorry - could not connect to specified Db" );

# create the query to select the records and then …
```

### Attempts to find solution

Initially I tried a simple substitution as recommended elsewhere.  But in the case of this page's code it did not work. I also looked at [Replaced $HTTP_GET_VARS with $_GET, but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814996) and it too did not solve the issue (see below attempt)

### Attempted New Code (PHP5)

Assuming a single table Db, with multiple columns, say 'alpha', 'bravo' and 'charlie', then rows of data in the table cells.  The now depreciated $HTTP_GET_VARS used to work fine:

```
    <?php
# Setting up Variables
unset($alpha, $bravo, $charlie);
while(list($key,$values) = each($alpha = $_GET['alpha'], $bravo = $_GET['bravo'], $charlie = $_GET['charlie']))
{
    $$key = $value;
}

#set query string, current_id and current_index
$query_string = "sound=$sound&hint=$hint&type=$type";

if(!isset($current_id)) $current_id = "";

if(!isset($current_index)) $current_index = "";

#connect to MySQL
$conn = @mysql_connect( "localhost","xxxx","xxxx" )
  or die( "Sorry - could not connect to MySQL" );

#select the specified database
$rs = @mysql_select_db( "xxx", $conn )
  or die( "Sorry - could not connect to specified Db" );

# create the query to select the records and then...
```

The error I get with this code is: Notice: Undefined index: alpha in C:\wamp\www\page2.php on line 4

Comment: do you call the page correctly with site.php?alpha=whatever&bravo=whatsoever ?

Comment: Are you sure you've set 'alpha' as a get variable? The error states that it cannot find a key named 'alpha' in the $_GET array. You can check the $_GET contents by using print_r($_GET);

Comment: Replacing `$HTTP_GET_VARS` with `$_GET` should do it, what is the error msg you get if you do this?

Comment: 1) `print_r($_GET);` to see what data it contains, paying attention to multibyte characters and case-sensitivity, if any. It seems odd that you should get this message if you have actually set the variables you try and access, since `$_GET` should give you more availability, not less. 2) `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);` - let's have a look at the raw data that's coming in. 3) Make sure you haven't POSTed the data by accident. 4) If you want to have the keys available as local variables and (correctly) have `register_globals` disabled, what's wrong with `extract($_GET);`?

Comment: By replacing $HTTP_GET_VARS with $_GET the error message I get is "Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in C:\wamp\www\page2.php on line 4"

Comment: My URL has the following vairables C:\wamp\www\page2.php?sound=1&hint=1&type=&current_index=0, where sound is on/off, hint is on/off and type is null for this page

Comment: I also see the following "Warning: each() expects exactly 1 parameter, 9 given in C:\wamp\www\page2.php on line 4" which is telling me "each($alpha = $_GET['alpha'], $bravo = $_GET['bravo'], $charlie = $_GET['charlie']))" is not the correct approach.

Comment: 1) print_r($_GET); gives Array ( [sound] => 1 [hint] => 1 [current_index] => 0 )

Comment: 1) print_r($_GET); gives Array ( [sound] => 1 [hint] => 1 [current_index] => 0 )
2) var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); gives string 'sound=1&hint=1&current_index=0' (length=30)
3) there is no POST
4) register_globals=Off...extract($_GET); sounds promising, as whilst I still get a bunch of warnings and Notices, the table is built below these.  Will respond after a bit more fiddling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4) If you want to have the keys available as local variables and (correctly) have register_globals disabled, what's wrong with extract($_GET);? – DaveRandom

From:

```
<?php
# Setting up Variables
unset($alpha, $bravo, $charlie);
while(list($key,$values) = each($alpha = $_GET['alpha'], $bravo = $_GET['bravo'], $charlie = $_GET['charlie']))
{
     $$key = $value;
}
```

To:

```
# Setting up Variables
unset($alpha, $bravo, $charlie);
extract($_GET);
```

Seems to have done the trick.

Thanks DaveRandom

Answer (score 0):

that is not an error, it is a notice - telling you some $_GET array index might not exist where you use it. You might look into php's `error_reporting()` and possibly set it to `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` at the very beginngin of the script to avoid notices - in your case that would probably suffice.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score -2):

Because you unset variables that aren't set yet
I think you have in php4 register_globals on and in php 5 off

register_globals is a bad thing so don't put it on

Comment: Ok :) checked line 3 my fault

Comment: No, the error is NOT the unset of the variables, the error (i.e. _notice_) occurs on accessing `alpha` in  `$_GET` so it seems, that they aren't specified in URL

Comment: My URL has the following vairables
C:\wamp\www\page2.php?sound=1&hint=1&type=&current_index=0, where sound is on/off, hint is on/off and type is null for this page